# what is the transferfrom event signature?

Tags: contract-deployment, contract-debugging, logs

I am currently writing a code that list all types of transactions in a given contract . my plan is to just check for all logs whether the topics[0] == an event signature of a function. and now i am missing the even signature of transferfrom. does anyone know the exact event signature of that so i can do the keccak hash of it that would be put in the topics[0]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `transferFrom` triggers a `Transfer` event. If you use open zeppelin then it also triggers an `Approval` event. There is not a `tranferFrom` event in the ERC20 standard.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const signature = Web3.utils.keccak256("Transfer(address,address,uint256)");
```

Tested with web3 v1.0.0-beta.34.